# How to modify html/css for http://twitter.com/*/following to use 100% width of page?

Tags: html, css, twitter, width

When seeing who someone follows on Twitter (e.g., https://twitter.com/BillGates/following), the page is formatted to only show 3 Twitter accounts per row.  What html/css do I modify on that page to take up 100% of the width, so that it shows the max amount of accounts per row based on window size?  Or, alternatively, how can I change the number from 3 to another number like 6?

Here's a marked-up screenshot illustrating what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's not about a number 3 or 6 it's about the width of the container div that includes the inner dive so If you wonna get it wider you have to make the width of the container bigger ie if you want it to include 6 per row you have to multibly the width with 2 
but I don't know if you can set this in twitter :)

Comment: I just want to know where I can change it dynamically (e.g., via Chrome Developer Tools / Inspect Element) when I load the page in the browser.  So which container div do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

here is the name of the container div:

```html
<div class="Grid-cell u-size2of3 u-lg-size3of4">
```